# How to remove subdomains without hardcode URL with nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have this domain structure and need make some redirect like:

```
sub1.sub2.sub3.domain.com/path -> sub2.sub3.domain.com/path
sub2.sub3.domain.com/path -> sub3.domain.com/path
sub1.domain1.com/path1 -> domain1.com/path1
sub2.domain1.com/path2 -> domain1.com/path2
sub3.sub4.domain1.com/path -> sub4.domain1.com/path
sub4.domain.uk.co/path -> sub4.domain1.uk.co/path

sub5.domain6.com/path3 -> domain6.com/path3
sub7.domain6.com/path4 -> domain6.com/path4
sub8.sub8.domain9.com/path5 -> sub8.domain9.com/path5
www.domain9.com/path5 -> domain9.com/path5
```

"domain.com" "domain6.com" "domain9.com" "domain1.uk.co" isn't host in this server.

I need redirect without hardcode any domain name. I try this:

```
if ( $host ~ ^www\.(.+)$ ) {
    set $without_www $1;
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$without_www$uri permanent;
}
```

But I need hadcoding "www" (and subXXX). How can I get the part before the point and dispose at the new address?

Comment: How are you going to distinguish `sub3` (needed to be removed) from `sub4` (not needed to be removed)?

Comment: Simple. You only have to remove the first subdomain.

Comment: Ok. You redirected `sub3.sub4.domain.com` to `sub4.domain.com`. Your server got a completely new request. How would you know you don't need to redirect the `sub4.domain.com` to `domain.com`?

Comment: sub4.domain.com need redirect to domain.com. But I can: 1º request: sub3.sub4.domain.com -> sub4.domain.com 2º request sub4.domain.com -> domain.com (NOTE: Domain.com use other diferent server)

Comment: You can try to redirect anything with the `if ($host ~ \w+\.(?<basedomain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)$) { rewrite ^ $scheme://$basedomain$request_uri permanent; }`, but it won't work with the two-component TLDs like `co.uk`, `com.au` etc.

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes I have two-component TLDs (recursion isn't a problem. This ngix server only "remove" subdomains)

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1039831/498657) answer (and the whole thread too). If such a guess is ok for you (*since the national TLDs are always [two letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Country_code_top-level_domains), we can assume that any `.xx.xx` and `.xxx.xx` domain suffix is very likely some national two component TLD*), you can use two `if` blocks - first one to check if the base domain has two-component TLD and second one like have been shown in comments:

```
if ($host ~ "\w+\.(?<basedomain>[^.]+\.\w{2,3}\.\w{2})$") {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$basedomain$request_uri permanent;
}
if ($host ~ \w+\.(?<basedomain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)$) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$basedomain$request_uri permanent;
}
```

To remove subdomains recursively one-by-one you can try the following:

```
if ($host ~ "^[^.]+\.(?<domain>(?!\w{2,3}\.\w{2}$)[^.]+\..+)$") {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$domain$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: @VictorSanchez Check the update.

Comment: @VictorSanchez I forgot that you need to use quotes when regex pattern contains a curly bracket. Check now, pls.

Comment: @VictorSanchez Try this one.

Comment: I don't understand the magic of the regular expression, but it works. Thanks!!

Comment: I tried it in more detail, and it doesn't work in some cases. xxxxxx.abc.es -> don't work.

Comment: Looks like you don't read the whole answer carefully, do you? It won't work for `*.abc.es` since it make a guess everything like `.xxx.xx` or `.xx.xx` is a two-component TLD. I suggest you to read the whole SF thead, but look at least at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1039781/is-there-a-variable-containing-the-domain-name-in-nginx/1039831#comment1353596_1039781) comment. The only reliable way do detect TLD correctly is to hardcode the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat), everything else will be a (better or worse) workaround.